# Elixir: Mix aliases, two `run` tasks in one alias

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

When setting aliases like:

```
defp aliases do
    [
      test_run: ["run -e 'IO.puts(\"One\")'", "run -e 'IO.puts(\"Two\")'"]
    ]
end
```

The result of `mix test_run` should be

```
$ mix test_run
One
Two
```

But it only executes the first task and prints

```
$ mix test_run
One
```

Not sure if it's intended behaviour, but before putting an issue I wanted to make sure.
Here is the repository to reproduce the error:
https://github.com/wende/mix_run_twice

Comment: I am also not sure if it is intended, but even trying `run` twice in `mix do` doesn't work: `MIX_DEBUG=1 mix do run -e 'IO.puts("one")', run -e 'IO.puts("two")'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mix does not allow a task to be run twice. You can however, use [Mix.Task.reenable/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/mix/Mix.Task.html#reenable/1) to run it again.

```
  test_run: ["run -e 'IO.puts(\"One\"); Mix.Task.reenable(:run)'", "run -e 'IO.puts(\"Two\")'"]
```

You must reenable the task at the end of the first `run` otherwise it will never get to the second task. You can't do something like:

```
 ["run -e 'IO.puts(\"One\")'", "run -e 'Mix.Task.reenable(:run)'"]
```

I would suggest making a custom mix task which calls [Mix.Task.run/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/mix/Mix.Task.html#run/2) for each task you want to run, reenabling as you go. Elixir 1.3 will make this easier by providing a `rerun/2` function that does the `reenable` and `run` for a task. https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/pull/4394

Comment: It seems to be the only solution for now. But it looks more like a way around the problem